# How can I compare 2 fields and input a result in Django

Tags: django, django-views

I know this is probably very basic stuff but I'm really having a tough time figuring it out. I have an app that stores sports forecasts for users, so they input the home team, it's score and the visiting team with it's score. The idea is for the app to determine whether the result was a home win, a tie or an away win by comparing the scores on both input boxes.

This is my view:

```
def inicio(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = Pronosticos(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pronostico = PartidosUsuarios.objects.get_or_create(idUsuario=request.user, idPartido=request.POST.get("idPartido", ""), PaisL=request.POST.get("PaisL", ""), Local=request.POST.get("Local", ""), Visita=request.POST.get("Visita", ""), PaisV=request.POST.get("PaisV", ""), Capturado="Si")
            if pronostico.Local > pronostico.Visita:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Local"
            elif pronostico.Visita > pronostico.Local:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Visita"
            elif pronostico.Local == pronostico.Visita:
                pronostico.Resultado = "Empate"
            return render(request, "brasil/inicio.html")
    partidos_fifa = PartidosFifa.objects.order_by("Partido")[:64]
    context = {"partidos_fifa": partidos_fifa}
    return render(request, "brasil/inicio.html", context)
```

The form:

```
class Pronosticos(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = PartidosUsuarios
        fields = ["idPartido", "PaisL", "Local", "Visita", "PaisV"]
```

and the model:

```
class PartidosUsuarios(models.Model):
    idUsuario = models.OneToOneField(User)
    idPartido = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    PaisL = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Local = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    Visita = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    PaisV = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Resultado = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    Puntos = models.IntegerField(max_length=11, default=0)
    Capturado = models.CharField(max_length=10, default="No")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.idPartido)
```

The field in question aka where i want the result to be stored is called "Resultado"

Everything works as it should except for this part where i've been getting this error:

AttributeError at /inicio/
'tuple' object has no attribute 'Local'

It's complaining about this line:
if pronostico.Local > pronostico.Visita:

Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the return value from `get_or_create()`. From [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#get-or-create):

> Returns a tuple of (object, created), where object is the retrieved or created object and created is a boolean specifying whether a new object was created.

So try this instead:

```
pronostico, _ = PartidosUsuarios.objects.get_or_create(...)
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin, it's not showing an error anymore, however it's also not saving the appropriate answer in "Resultado" which should be either "Local", "Empate" or "Visita" do you have a way to do this? what am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user3605164: It looks like you're not calling `pronostico.save()`. When you assign to `prognostico.Resultado` you're changing the in-memory version of the object, but you need to call `save()` to persist that change to the database.

Comment: That was it! Thank you very much I had gotten confused with using get_or_create and save methods in the same view.